# C++ Ввести матрицу с помощью диагоналей

Tags: c++, массивы

Ввести квадратную матрицу с помощью диагоналей. То есть, сначала вводится основная диагональ, затем диагональ на одну сроку ниже а последний элемент данной строки (который не войдет в диапазон матрицы необходимо перенести в верхний правый угол) и т.д. Просьба в решении задачи не использовать ф-цию vector.

Пример (цифры представлены просто для наглядности работы диагоналей, матрица может быть любого размера ):

```
1***     1**2     1*32
*1**     21**     21*3
**1*     *21*     321*
***1     **21     *321
```

Мой код но без переноса элементов не входящих в диапазон матрицы:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;

int mat[n][n];
for(int i=0; i<(n); i++)
 for(int j=0; j<(n); j++)
{
    if (j+i>j+j){i=0;} //Данная часть не работает
    cin>>mat[j+i][j];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно и без функций обнуления массива и его вывода.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// контроль выхода индекса за размер массива
int ControlIndex(int matrixIndex, uint sizeMatrix)
{
    if (matrixIndex >= sizeMatrix)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // то есть, ничего не делаем с индексом
        return matrixIndex;
    }
}

// показать матрицу
void ShowMatrix(int** matrix, int sizeMatrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeMatrix; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeMatrix; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

// заполнить матрицу нулями
void FillMatrix(int** matrix, int sizeMatrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeMatrix; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeMatrix; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // переменная, корректирующая переход строк, в случае выхода за размер массива
    int rowCorrection = 0;

    uint SIZE;
    cout << "Size: ";
    cin >> SIZE;

    // выделяем память массиву двумерному
    int** matrix = new int*[SIZE];

    // выделяем память каждому одномерному массиву двумерного массива
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[SIZE];
    }

    // сразу заполним матрицу нулями и покажем ее исходное состояние
    FillMatrix(matrix, SIZE);
    ShowMatrix(matrix, SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            // ввод чисел по диагонали
            // если индекс >= SIZE, то строка вновь становится 0 и каждую
            // итерацию увеличивается на 1
            // а столбцы независимо продолжают увеличиваться
            cin >> matrix[ControlIndex(j+i, SIZE) + rowCorrection][j];

            if (j + i >= SIZE)
            {
                // за счет этого, у нас индекс строки продолжает увеличиваться
                // даже после ее обнуления после выхода за размер массива
                rowCorrection++;
            }

            // выводим матрицу каждый раз после ввода числа
            ShowMatrix(matrix, SIZE);
            cout << endl;
        }

        // после ввода диагонали, обнуляем коррекцию
        rowCorrection = 0;

    }

     ShowMatrix(matrix, SIZE);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```